# Twitter4j throws 401 authentication errors

Tags: twitter4j

I am getting the following authentication error when trying to access Twitter using my own credentials. Can someone tell what the problem could be?

401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.

```
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.953 sec <<< FAILURE!
showStatusTest(com.mycompany.twitter.test.TwitterClientTest)  Time elapsed: 0.672 sec  <<< ERROR!
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6b80c41c-1bd1da85], statusCode=401, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5-SNAPSHOT(build: 5f9c44cd0e0c1972f8d17653a226b9b6a3392ac2)}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1869)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.showStatus(TwitterImpl.java:445)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
```

The above exception was solved by setting the appropriate `system clock in sync`.

Comment: What is system clock and how to sync it ?

Comment: @Dharmendra - i.e. System clock is out of sync. Don't know which distro you are using, but sync the clock made it and work for me.

Comment: Which clock I have to sync? is it system clock or emulator clock.Can you please provide description ?

Comment: @Dharmendra its just System clock is out of sync. you just install  Network Time Protocol for clear this issue

Comment: The answer is partial since even after resetting the clock using NTP the only disappear for a few minutes and then return. is happens to me under Akka technology

Answer (score 0):

Have you supplied correct consumer keys and access tokens in the application..? Read [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)